# Sitecore complex type field- name value with dropdown list

Tags: fieldtype

Is there any complex field type available in Sitecore with Name value + dropdown list?

some thing like : Key + value + Dropdownlist

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, there is not.

Neil Shack assembled a [list of all available field types](https://nshackblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/07/full-list-of-sitecore-field-types-and-their-c-type-mapping/). While it is not 100% up to date, it is current enough to use as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, You can use **Name Lookup Value List**, This field type is an extended version of Name Value List type having many of the similar features. The only difference here is – Name Lookup Value List uses a Dropdown list to choose the value against a key. The editor is still required to type the key name, the dropdown is only for Value field.
[image]

**Update** - Okay so the original question is updated, so answer for this is **NO** , There is no any OOTB field avaible for this but you can do this by two ways first creating a custom field type second use the **Name Lookup Value List** but with a twist, by adding both name and value in the first textbox of the field with _(underscore) as identifier for name and value - **Name_Value**
Although this will require some knowledge transfer to the content editor that how they can use this field. In code, you can simply split the name value with _ (underscore).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "Name Value List" or "Name Lookup Value List" field type. Probably this will serve your purpose of Name+Value for dropdown. To check more out-of-box field types, please see [Sitecore Field Types](https://sitecore.namics.com/2018/12/20/cheatsheetfieldtypes/). If out-of-box field types will not be used in your scenario you may add your own field types following this link [Create Sitecore Custom Field Type](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/en/create-a-custom-field-type.html)

Comment: I am looking for any OOB complex type.

Comment: OOTB field is not available. you can write your own custom field type as per need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Express Subitem](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Express_Subitem.aspx) from Sitecore Marketplace that allows you to add multiple 'complex' fields within the context of a current item.

[image]